# 403 Forbidden error when I tried to assign a user developer role using GitLab API through Python code

Tags: gitlab, python-gitlab

I have written a Python program using FastAPI and the python-gitlab library (https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ ) to provide the developer role on the GitLab project repository to the users but I'm getting the 403 Forbidden error.
Here is code snippet:-

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
import requests
import gitlab

app = FastAPI()

# GitLab API configuration
GITLAB_API_URL = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4"
PRIVATE_TOKEN = ""
NAMESPACE = "mycompany"
PROJECT_NAME = "test-project"

def grant_developer_access(username: str):
 # Get user details from GitLab
 user_url = f"{GITLAB_API_URL}/users?username={username}"
 response = requests.get(user_url, headers={"PRIVATE-TOKEN": PRIVATE_TOKEN})
    user_data = response.json()
 if not user_data:
 raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail=f"User {username} not found.")
 print('user_data', user_data)
    user_id = user_data[0]["id"]

# Grant developer access to the project
 access_data = {"user_id": user_id, "access_level": 30}  # 30 is the access level for developer
 project_id = get_project_id(PROJECT_NAME)
 print('project_id', project_id)
    access_url = f"{GITLAB_API_URL}/projects/{project_id}/access_requests"
 print('access_url', access_url)
    response = requests.post(access_url, headers={"PRIVATE-TOKEN": PRIVATE_TOKEN}, json=access_data)
 print('response->', response)
```

Both my 1st API call (to fetch the user data) and the 2nd API call (not shown here though) to fetch the GitLab project ID against the project name work fine but the problem comes on the last API call when I try to give the developer access to the user using this Post call, `response = requests.post(access_url, headers={"PRIVATE-TOKEN": PRIVATE_TOKEN}, json=access_data)`  It is giving me 403 forbidden error.
Just FYI, the namespace and project are related to my company's internal GitLab instance and the user to whom I'm trying to give the developer access role on a specific project repository is also an internal employee who has an account on GitLab (to other repositories though) then why this 403 error is coming. I'm very close to it complete it but this issue is throwing me out again. I would appreciate the help in letting me know what the issue is. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This method will work

```
gl = gitlab.Gitlab(gitlab_url, private_token=private_token)
user = gl.users.list(username="username")[0]
user_id = user.id
project = gl.projects.get(project_id)

project.members.create({'user_id': user.id, 'access_level': 
gitlab.DEVELOPER_ACCESS})
```

You can also provide constants to represent the access level i.e 30 for developer access

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).